# Heroku file backup without s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backup, attachment, redmine

I have a Redmine ([www.redmine.org](http://www.redmine.org)) installation pushed up onto Heroku (cedar stack).  On my local instance of Redmine, the way file uploads work is that the database simply stores some data about the file including a name and the location of the file on disk, and the file itself is just stored on disk under `[app-location]/files` (Redmine is a ruby-on-rails application).  When my Redmine project is pushed to Heroku, the `files` directory is nowhere to be found. From what I've read about Heroku's filesystem, this is no surprise.  But what is surprising and confusing, is that file uploads still work and I didn't setup s3 which is the common recommendation for file uploads on Heroku.  I checked the Heroku database to get the data about the file upload.

Here are the steps I took to locate the file.

```
heroku run rails c
```

and – *to get the location of the most recent file* – ran:

```
Attachment.last.diskfile
```

which returned:

`=> "/app/files/2014/06/140610184025_Very-Basic-Globe-icon.png"`

This path simply does not exist on the Heroku instance (using `heroku run bash` and listing directories or running a find). I also downloaded a dump of the Heroku database and imported it locally.  The database data shows up on my local instance, but the file can't be found (no surprise).

So my questions are:

1. Where is the Heroku instance storing the files really?
2. Is there a way for me to back those files up locally without relying
   on Amazon s3?

This app should remain fairly small, so I am not concerned about massive scalability, I just want to be able to get the file uploads if one day needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, and you may have already found a solution, but just in case other people stumble on this question:

1. Heroku really is storing the files where it says it is. What's happening when you run `heroku run bash` is Heroku is spinning up a *[one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos)* to run the command. This means that you will not be given a command prompt in the dyno that is actually running your app. This is why you are not able to find the file you're looking for.
2. There are currently no official [addons](https://addons.heroku.com) that support backing up physical files (only databases), however you could write your own custom script to back up your data to where ever you choose (s3 or otherwise). To do so, you will likely need to use [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) to run your backup script in a cron-like way.

Comment: I just noticed this response.  Thanks for your time.  I have since abandoned running Redmine on Heroku and went to a Google Server instead. But your answer is adequate for the question.  I may look into using a script on the Heroku Scheduler in the future, though. Thank you.

Comment: How do I get into the dyno that is actually running my app? I need to confirm if the file is actually there.